# Is there a way to change name of shared library output from cython w/o using distutils?

Tags: python, cython

Cython code can be compiled as

```
cython hello.pyx -o hello.c
gcc -shared -fPIC hello.c -o hello.so `pkg-config python --libs --cflags`
```

But if you change `hello.so` above to `hello2.so`, the module will fail to import in python due to assumptions that a function `inithello2` will exist in a python module `hello2.so`. With distutils, you can change the name using a keyword to setup(name='hello2', ...). But I need to get this functionality without using distutils. Can it be done?